# Can I use stands/sits/lies?

Tags: word-choice

> A bird cage stands/sits on the table.

Could I use both? Which one is more natural?

> A laptop stands/sits/lies on the nightstand.

Could I use them all? Which one is most natural?

> A cell phone sits/lies on the nightstand.

Could I use both? Which one is more natural?

Answer (score 1):

Since all of them are metaphorical, the most natural one is the one that represents the position best.

> The birdcage sits on the table.

It occupies both width and height, like a sitting person.

> The laptop lies/sits on the nightstand.

I would use "lies" if it's closed, and "sits" if it's open.  Closed, it's clearly mostly width.

> A cell phone lies on the nightstand

It is clearly mostly width.  It would, however, stand in a charger.

Answer (score 0):

A bird cage sits on the table.
A pole lamp stands on the floor.
A laptop lies on the nightstand.
A cellphone lies on the nightstand.

I think those would be the best choices. You wouldn't usually use "stands" on an elevated surface.